# Primefaces fileUpload using weblogic

Tags: java, jsf, file-upload, primefaces

I'm using fileUpload component on Tomcat server and it does work correctly. when i tried my app on weblogic server, the file upload component wasn't working.

```
<h:form id="fileUpoad" prependId="false" enctype="multipart/form-data">

    <!-- File Upload with  mode="advanced". multiple files can be uploaded. upload button  -->

    <h:outputLabel for="fileIdPhoto" value="Hasar fotografini yukleyiniz:"/>

    <p:fileUpload id="fileIdPhoto" fileUploadListener="#{fileUploadBean.uploadPhoto}" mode="advanced"
                  dragDropSupport="false"
                  multiple="true" update="messages" sizeLimit="10000000" fileLimit="3"
                  allowTypes="/(\.|\/)(gif|jpe?g|zip)$/"/>

    <p:messages id="messages" autoUpdate="true" closable="true"/>

</h:form>
```

Here is my `fileUpload` bean:

```
@ManagedBean(name = "fileUploadBean")
@RequestScoped
public class fileUpload {
    FileUploadEvent e;

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    private String name;

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String uploadPhoto() throws IOException {
        System.out.println("resim kaydetme metoduna girildi");

        UploadedFile uploadedPhoto = e.getFile();

        String filePath = "c:/temp/kk";
        byte[] bytes = null;

        if (null != uploadedPhoto) {
            bytes = uploadedPhoto.getContents();
            String filename = FilenameUtils.getName(uploadedPhoto.getFileName());
            BufferedOutputStream stream = new BufferedOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(new File(filePath + filename)));
            stream.write(bytes);
            stream.close();
        }
        System.out.println("resim kaydettim cikiyorum");
        FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().addMessage("messages", new FacesMessage(FacesMessage.SEVERITY_INFO, "(File Name " + uploadedPhoto.getFileName() + " with size " + uploadedPhoto.getSize() + ")  Basarili bir sekilde kaydedildi", ""));

        return null;
    }
}
```

when i clicked "upload" , my image wasn't saving. here is my weblogic server error:

> Oct 31, 2016 7:54:49 AM com.sun.faces.context.ExternalContextImpl
>   getMimeType WARNING: JSF1091: No mime type could be found for file
>   /denemexhtml.xhtml.  To resolve this, add a mime-type mapping to the
>   applications web.xml. Oct 31, 2016 7:54:49 AM
>   com.sun.faces.context.ExternalContextImpl getMimeType WARNING:
>   JSF1091: No mime type could be found for file /denemexhtml.xhtml.  To
>   resolve this, add a mime-type mapping to the applications web.xml.

Comment: show the code of your FileUploadBean please as well as put the description of error/exception you got.

Comment: And "wasn't working" is to vague. Please investigate more

Comment: read this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39486157/get-uploaded-file-path-in-primefaces/39487964#39487964 and flow the same steps

Comment: when i clicked "upload" , i have error.                                                     here is error: javax.el.MethodNotFoundException error

Comment: Then first find the cause of that error. Many posts about that specific error in Stackoverflow

Answer (score 0):

Why you're returning a String in your uploadPhoto method?

I guess it doesn't find the uploadPhoto method? The FileUploadEvent shouldn't be a global variable, you should give it to your method (I guess that's the cause of your error):

```
public String uploadPhoto(FileUploadEvent e)
```

or better as I said without String:

```
public void uploadPhoto(FileUploadEvent e)
```

Be also aware of your path. Most probably the windows path will not work on your server. You also don't create the directories via file.mkdirs() before you attemp to write the file, so if the directories do not exist you'll get an error too.